# actionscript 3.0: dynamically load fonts

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

with actionscript 3.0 it is possible to embed a font in a single swf file.

but is it also possible to load this swf after the main movie has started or do they need to be loaded at the beginning?

thanks!

Comment: This is possible. Check this [blog entry](http://nochump.com/blog/archives/20) out for more details.

Comment: thanks, btw do you if there is a way to determine when a textfield is used which font has not been loaded yet?

Comment: You could implement some sort of font manager to keep track of which fonts you have loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing is to embed them in a stylesheet (.css)

```
@font-face {
    src: url("../assets/MyriadWebPro.ttf");
    fontFamily: myFontFamily;
}
```

(http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=fonts_04.html)

Compile it separately (in **Flash Builder**, right-click the .css and select **Compile CSS to SWF**), and load it when you need it (**StyleManager.loadStyleDeclarations**)